# How to get a dataset of twitter followers list?

Tags: twitter, dataset

I need to get a twitter or any other social network dataset that has the followers list (not the number of followers but i need the follower id).

I need atleast the following details of a user in the following format:

Userid,username,followersids....

I would like to get the whole network dataset in a csv file
From where can I gert the dataset. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked their API?

Comment: Yes. But it is taking lot of time to get all the followers using API. That's why I a m looking for some dataset already available.